# Querying data from the table and converting it into the required JSON format through spring MVC

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I want to fetch data from the following table like -

```
+------------+----------------+------------+
|     No     |    trackingNo  | customerNo |
+------------+----------------+------------+
| 055162     | 78Q6156        |     281478 |
| 055161     | 78Q6293        |     281478 |
| 0551629    | 78Q68431       |     281480 |
| 055131870  | 78Q63189       |     281480 |
| 055131870  | 78Q625771      |     281480 |
+------------+----------------+------------+
```

through grouping by `customerNo` I  have to query the data and then through MVC API get the data and convert it to the below JSON format.
How can I query the data from this table through MySQL.

The expected JSON format output to be

```
  {
  [
   {
    "customerNo": 281478,
    "details": [
      {
        "No": "055162",
        "trackingNo": "78Q6156" 
      },
      {
        "No": "055161",
        "trackingNo": "78Q6293"
      }
     ]
    },
    {
    "customerNo": 281480,
    "details": [
      {
        "No": "0551629",
        "trackingNo": "78Q68431"
      },
      {
        "No": "055131870",
        "trackingNo": "78Q63189"
      },
      {
        "No": "055131870",
        "trackingNo": "78Q625771"
      }
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: kalpana kanyal, you didn't exactly ask a question, can you clarify what exactly you want to know? At the moment it's unclear to me whether you're having troubles with connecting to the MySQL database, with fetching the data, grouping the data or showing a JSON response. Can you clarify that in your question and post the relevant code if you have some? That makes it a lot easier for us to pinpoint the problem. If you need to know all of those things, I suggest you break down your question into multiple questions, as that would be too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use spring jpa that you have to configure through your application.properties file into your spring boot project. 
But finaly, the best way for you to learn how to this is to pick the spring-boot petclinic project on github :  [Spring-petclinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should alter your database schema. Instead of having all of this in one table, you should have a customer table containing the `customerNo` as Id and maybe some other fields to describe your customer.
You can create a second table named details for example with the field `No` as Id and the `trackingNo`. Further you need to have your `customerId` as foreign key in this table as well.

Now you can make use of springs ability to connect parent and child entities by using the `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` Annotations.
Basically you would have your customer entity be the parent with a one to many relation to the details entity.
In the details entity you would have a many to one relation to your customer entity.

As this is quite a broad question I can just give you these hints and find out yourself how to code them.